# how to pass value to query in same page in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a dropdown box

```
<select>
<option value=1>A</option>
<option value=2>B</option>
</select>
```

in the php code i have a query

```
<?php $sql='select * from table where id='.'SELECTOPTIONVALUE' ?>
```

I need to pass selected value in where clause (id=SELECTOPTIONVALUE)
how to pass value in where clause from dropdown...Any Help..

Thanks,

Nawaz

Comment: Be aware https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: This code is incredibly dangerous for your server, since you are directy injecting a variable into your query. Please consider using PDO instead for such a treatment of variables, this code is exposing you to potential SQL injections, which should be avoided even before attempting to pass a variable to that other page ;)

Comment: This is not the best practice to have sql code and html code on same page. Separate them and use ajax or form submit event to pass the selected value of dropdown

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168156/7842542

Answer (score 0):

I think below code help you to resolve problem

```
 <?php 
    $sql = 'select * from table where id = '.$_GET['selected'].' ' ;
    ?>
    <select name="selected" id="model">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1" <?php if($_GET['selected'] == 1) echo 'selected';?> >A</option>
        <option value="2"  <?php if($_GET['selected'] == 2) echo 'selected';?>>B</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var select = document.getElementById("model");
        select.onchange = function(){
            var selectedString = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
            window.location = "http://localhost/stack/stack-q/2.php?selected="+selectedString;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: the form is not submitted

Comment: then you need javascript

Comment: Please edit your answer to fix this error: `<?php $sql='select * from table where id = $_POST['selected']  ?>` won't work, should be something like `<?php $sql="select * from table where id = {$_POST['selected']}"; ?>`.

Comment: @Barclick Flores Velasquez ...thats how?

Comment: your select query and form in same page or different page ? @NawazAhmed

Comment: same page @JYoThI

Comment: just update full code of page using edit button  @NawazAhmed